# VisualForce : CustomController Vs CustomListController

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

I am bit confused between Custom Controller and Custom List Controller difference.

The reason being ,In Customer controller i can create a method to return list of accounts which i can use in Visualforce page then what is the use case for me to opt Custom List controller (account).?

What is that i can do with Custom List controller which cannot be achieved with Custom Controller.

Answer (score 1):

We use to customize controller when that cannot be achieved through either StandardController or StandardSetController.

Usage:

Custom controller can act on single record, where as CustomListController is applicable on a set of records.

Think about a scenario, where we need to create/update an account and same time need to show list of contact records in a `paginated` way and that contact records can also be updated.

In this scenario, we can use both combination of CustomController and CustomListController.

> Account create/update part will take care of CustomController

```
public class MyController {

    private final Account account;

    public MyController() {
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        update account;
        return null;
    }
}
```

> List of contacts can be displayed upon assigning the list as `ApexPages.StandardSetController`

Now we can leverage [StandardSetController methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) through CustomListController.

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon{get;set;}    

    setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                  [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId:acct]));
```

**Update**

From your comment you can get the list of contacts like this:

```
public List<Contact> contacts; 
     public List<Contact> getContacts()
     {  
            contacts = [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId:account.Id];    
     }
```

This `List` will not have all the methods of which has `StandardSetController` like

- first()
- getHasNext()
- getHasPrevious()
- getPageNumber()
- getRecord()
- last()
- next()
  etc.

From the List you have make custom coding for pagination and other stuffs. And that list `List<Contact>` will not provide the functionality of CustomListController.

Ideally we can give a name to any controller but, we need to be sure about for which purpose we are using.

For more information refer [Building a Custom Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm)  and [Building a Custom List Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm)

Comment: This i can even achieve by adding below code to your MyController class, What is the difference.

 public List<Contact> contacts;   
    
 public List<Contact> getContacts(){ 
  contacts = [SELECT Name, Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId:account.Id]; 
 }

Comment: updated my answer